# Unique representation via functional

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a normed space and $\alpha \in X^*$ be a functional that is not the zero functional. Suppose $c \notin \text{Ker}(\alpha)$. For each $a \in X$ can we write $a=b+kc$ for $b \in \text{Ker}(\alpha)$ where $k$ is some scalar?

My thought is yes, but the way I went about it almost feels like cheating. If $a \in \text{Ker}(\alpha)$, then we have $a = a + 0c$. If $a \notin \text{Ker}(\alpha)$, then $a = 0+1a$.

I don't know if this is the correct way to go about this and even if this representation is unique.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: $c \notin \mathrm{Ker}(\alpha)$ is *fixed*. If $a \notin \mathrm{Ker}(\alpha)$ you'd need to be very lucky to have $a = c$.

Comment: @UmbertoP.: You are right, I do not know how I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for a moment that $a = b + kc$ with $b \in \mathrm{Ker}(\alpha)$. If you apply $\alpha$ to both sides you obtain $$\alpha(a) = 0 + k \alpha (c)$$ which you can solve for $k$: $$k = \dfrac{\alpha(a)}{\alpha(c)}.$$ In fact this makes it possible to solve for $b$:
$$b = a - kc = a - \frac{\alpha(a)}{\alpha(c)}c.$$
This shows that if such a representation exists it must be unique. Turning things around you can write, for any $a$,
$$a = \left( a - \frac{\alpha(a)}{\alpha(c)}c \right) + \frac{\alpha(a)}{\alpha(c)}c.$$
To finish you just need to verify that $$\alpha \left( a - \frac{\alpha(a)}{\alpha(c)}c \right) = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you, for the detailed explanation.